# Bayer Demosaicing VideoCaptured frame in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently receiving a video stream from a camera that requires demosaicing.
The frame info is 480x640x3. dtype is uint8

When I try to use cv2.cvtColor to convert from BAYER to RGB I get,

> error: (-215:Assertion failed) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in
>   function 'cv::demosaicing'

I am unsure what the error means.
I am using the [OpenCV cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) as doc.

The code I am using is as follows:
The only part that I kept trying is changing cv2.COLOR_BayerGB2BGR

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    _, frame = cap.read()

    processedIm = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BayerGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow("Main", processedIm)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using OVRVision to obtain the image.
A little more info regarding the camera: [Processing Flowchart]  (http://ovrvision.com/files/docs/index.html#gscamprop)

As shown below the flow chart. The Image I obtain is flowchart.

Comment: Please share the code you are using ?

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: The error means, that either the source image does not have 1 channel or the output does not have 3 or 4 channels. The output is automatically generated and by your comment "The frame info is 480x640x3", the image has 3 channels... do you show it with imshow? does it gives unexpected results?

Comment: Please check the number of channels in `frame` using `print frame.shape`

Comment: @ZdaR  
print( frame.shape) gives (480, 640, 3)

Comment: @api55
I am not sure what you mean by source image does not have 1 channel?
It is a stereo camera. The link in the main post has the processing flowchart as well as an example of the image obtained directly from the camera.

Comment: VideoCapture connects to a camera using a backend (e.g. FFMpeg or GStreamer) and this tries to decode it and convert it to BGR and that is the image you get from `cap.read()`. For special cameras, this may fail or give unexpected results. That is why I ask, if you remove the cv2.cvtColor instruction, what do you see with imshow? is it normal colored image? Maybe the videoCapture class is too limited for the task

Comment: @api55  
The images I get without cv2.cvtColor is https://imgur.com/a/bRkfqUW

Comment: Maybe the information got decoded and it is in the first 2 channels? maybe something like `imshow("first channel", frame[:, :, 0])` and `imshow("second channel", frame[:, :, 1])` and `imshow("third channel", frame[:, :, 2])` may give you a clue how the data was decoded and convert it by OpenCV. My guess is that one channel will be mostly black and the other 2 will be the same image with a slight shift difference

Comment: @api55
Here is the channel split data along with the original frame. https://imgur.com/a/dCCupZt

Comment: I am out of ideas, but maybe you can use ffmpeg or gstreamer directly to get the data raw

Comment: you should use the SDK and/or look at "examples/
3rdparty/ : Other libraries which use with examples"

Comment: can you try to split the image channels (cv::split) and run the demosaicing on both channels individually?